# MassTransit riders Add ability to dynamically connect endpoints

Tags: masstransit

I would like to configure Add bus rider dynamically into a class not into startup.
Working well with RabbitMQ.
But I don't know how to Add Rider to my bus.

```cs
private IBusControl ConfigureBus()
        {
            var massTransitSection = this.configuration.GetSection("MassTransit");
            var url = massTransitSection.GetValue<string>("Url");
            var host = massTransitSection.GetValue<string>("Host");
            var userName = massTransitSection.GetValue<string>("UserName");
            var password = massTransitSection.GetValue<string>("Password");
            var busControl =
                Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.Host($"rabbitmq://{url}/{host}", configurator =>
                    {
                        configurator.Username(userName);
                        configurator.Password(password);
                    });
                    cfg.PublishTopology.BrokerTopologyOptions = PublishBrokerTopologyOptions.MaintainHierarchy;
                });
            busControl.StartAsync();

            
            return busControl;
        }
```

Thx a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Riders cannot be connected after the bus has been configured. Topic endpoints are also not able to be connected after the bus has been configured.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer.
So maybe I am missing part.
There is not possibility to configure a bus with riders 
somewhere else my startup.cs without DI ?
I was thinking CreateUsingRabbitMq was the place where I configure my bus.

Comment: Correct. Riders are only configurable via the container-based configuration.